# Executing Perl script from windows-command line with 2 entry

Tags: windows, bash, perl, command-line, cmd

this is my Perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

sub xml2array{
my $path = shift; 
my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parsefile($path); 
return map { $_ -> att('VirtualPath') } $twig -> get_xpath('//Signals');
} 

sub compareMappingToArray {
my $mapping = shift;
my $signalsRef = shift; 
my $i = 1;

print "In file : $mapping\n";

open(my $fh, $mapping);
while (my $r = <$fh>) {
    chomp $r; 


    if ($r =~ /\'(ModelSpecific.*)\'/) {
        my $s = $1;


        my @matches = grep { /^$s$/ } @{$signalsRef};

        print "line $i : not found - $s\n" if scalar @matches ==0;
        print "line $i : multiple $s\n" if scalar @matches > 1;
    }

    $i = $i + 1 # keep line index
 }
}

my $mapping = "C:/Users/HOR1DY/Desktop/Global/TA_Mapping/CAN/CAN_ESP_002_mapping.pm";      
my @virtualpath = xml2array("SignalModel.xml");
compareMappingToArray($mapping,  \@virtualpath);
```

The script works well, the aim of it is to compare the file "SignalModel.xml" and "CAN_ESP_002_mapping.pm" and putting the lines that didn't matches in a .TXT file. Here is how the .TXT file looks like:

```
In file : C:/Users/HOR1DY/Desktop/Global/TA_Mapping/CAN/CAN_ESP_002_mapping.pm
line 331 : not found - ModelSpecific.EID.NET.CAN_Engine.VCU.Transmit.VCU_202.R2B_VCU_202__byte_3
line 348 : not found - ModelSpecific.EID.NET.CAN_Engine.CMM_WX.Transmit.CMM_HYB_208.R2B_CMM_HYB_208__byte_2
line 368 : not found - ModelSpecific.EID.NET.CAN_Engine.VCU.Transmit.VCU_222.R2B_VCU_222__byte_0
```

But for this script, I put the two files that need to be compare inside of the code and instead of doing that, I would like to run the script in windows cmd line and having something like:

```
C:\Users>perl CANMappingChecker.pl -'file 1' 'file 2'
```

All the files are in .zip file so if I can execute the script that he goes inside and take the 2 files that I need for comparison, it should be perfect.
I really don't know how to do and what to put inside my script to make that in the cmd windows. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Program (or script) parameters are stored in the @ARGV array. [shift](http://p3rl.org/shift) and [pop](http://p3rl.org/pop) without any parameter will work on @ARGV when used outside of a sub, in a sub they operate on @_.

See [Archive::Zip](http://p3rl.org/Archive::Zip) for zip file handling.